# Unchanged meetings always prompt to save changes in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, meetings

If I open any meeting in Outlook 2016, then close without making any changes, it always prompts to save changes. This only started happening recently. It doesn't happen for appointments. Any ideas on why this might suddenly be happening, and how to stop it?

UPDATE: While this does not seem to be happening on current versions of Outlook, a related issue with slightly different repro steps still happens as described in the feedback link to from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1782170/103148).

Answer (score 14):

Possible solution that worked for me:
disable "show weather on the calendar" under File->Options->Calendar

You may have to restart Outlook for the solution to work.

Comment: you are a true American hero (or an international hero).  Disabling the stupid weather option worked for me. Thanks and here have an upvote. I'd give you a billion if I could. Welcome to StackExchange.

Comment: This is it.  Worked for me as well.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for calendar items you currently have open but will for any ones opened subsequently.

Comment: Still relevant after 2 additional years. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Option is already disabled in my settings, but Outlook still asks to save changes. Note that this happen only after the Meeting window stays open and I lock/unlock my Windows session.

Comment: I can't possibly express how much I appreciate this. If I could share some of my reputation with as thanks, I would.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that when you click on a link (e.g. to open a Zoom or Webex link) you have clicked into the body of the meeting causing the application goes into Edit mode. Once it's been in edit mode, it cannot be closed until you save or discard changes.

Comment: OP does not mention clicking a link in the event.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case for me.  Open a meeting, then close it - no prompt.  Open a meeting, click on a link, then close meeting - I get prompted.  This makes sense, as the link is being updated with a different color.  In my case, these are Zoom meeting links.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open Outlook in safe mode : `Outlook.exe /safe`.

If this no longer happens, then the problem is with some installed add-on.
Try in this case to disable add-ons until you find the problematic one.

Comment: Happens even with safe mode on 

Comment: You might try to uninstall and reinstall Outlook (or Office if that's the case).

Comment: Unfortunatelly Office is centrally deployed so I have no way of reinstalling.

Comment: @BenjaminMesing: You might be able to ask the administrator to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you open an attachment in the email? This could error if you have opened an attachment of that message.

If this is not your case, I think this may be related with data file. You can repair outlook data files to see if it helps.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another web site. "I have discovered that if I open the meeting on my main laptop screen, I don't get the prompt to save changes.  However, if I open the meeting on my extended desktop screen, the prompt is displayed every time."

Comment: OP does not mention a second screen

Answer (score 0):

The issue was raised to Microsoft and can be upvoted on their [feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/8ff1b272-748e-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0)